# How to "cite" MathOverflow answer?

Tags: discussion, citations

I am writing a paper at the moment and for one proof I use an idea which I got from a MathOverflow answer (at the time I was asking idle questions but later of course found a way to use it). I of course feel uncomfortable just giving the idea without credit but I'm not really sure how to do it. What's the convention here? You ask if it's ok to just thank them informally in the paper or....???

Comment: You may notice that under each answer there is a button demarked "cite" -- if you click on it, you'll get the bibtex info for how to cite the answer. IMO it is ethically necessary to cite the MO answer in question.

Comment: Ah great! I never noticed, thank you!

Comment: I'll copy my comment [from the original post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/327155/timeline) which was somehow lost in migration. Academia Stack Exchange: [Attributing contributions to academic work that occur in Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1580) and [How to acknowledge a MathOverflow user?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107963) You might also have a look at post on MathOverflow Meta [tagged citations](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/citations).